# SFTP Connector Keep File on Error

Tags: mule, mule-component

Mule is not keeping file in source folder in case of any error occurred during execution despite of having selected the option for Keep File On Error in connector configuration. 
Any pointers on this strange behavior?

Comment: Are you using both inbound and outbound are SFTP?

Comment: Please include source code and any error information.

Comment: One thing to note is that the Keep File on Error option assumes that both the inbound and outbound endpoints are using the SFTP transport. If your outbound is not SFTP, that may be the reason.

Comment: Yes both inbound and outbound is using SFTP transport. Sending you the entire code in chunks for your quick reference.

Comment: 1)--------------
<sftp:connector name="SFTP" validateConnections="true"  doc:name="SFTP" keepFileOnError="true" />
    <object-to-string-transformer name="Object_to_String" doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <object-to-byte-array-transformer name="Object_to_Byte_Array" doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
    <mulerequester:config name="Mule_Requester" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>

Comment: 2) --------- if you look closely i have selected keepFileOnError=true

<sftp:connector name="SFTPOut" validateConnections="true" duplicateHandling="addSeqNo" doc:name="SFTP" autoDelete="false" keepFileOnError="true"/>

Comment: 3) --------------
<flow name="sftpdemoFlow">
<sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP" host="localhost" port="22" path="/input" user="tester" password="password" responseTimeout="30000"  doc:name="SFTP" transformer-refs="Object_to_Byte_Array" pollingFrequency="10000"/>
<byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
<sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="SFTPOut" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" host="localhost" port="22" path="/output" user="tester" password="password" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"/>

Comment: Just to generate the error, I am renaming output folder to output1 and then running the flow, I observed that, SFTP inbound is consuming the files, but when flow fails at outbound, it is not keeping the in input folder. Ideally it should. Please help me understanding if I am wrong.

Comment: I suggested an answer to add the attribute, _keepFileOnError="true"_, in the sftp:outboud-endpoint, but I found this does not work either. Looking at the debug information from Mule and the code within, it appears that Mule closes and deletes the file in the post process of the SftpInputStream. It does this **before** it attempts to connect to the outbound-endpoint where your error occurs.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.... seems it's a bug from Mule side.